# killing a thread from the calling function c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, kill

I have button call this code

```
private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread My_Thread = new Thread(() => Send_File());
    My_Thread.IsBackground = true;
    My_Thread.Start();
}
```

I want a way to kill

> My_Thread

from the function

> Send_File()

please help me how to fix it ??? :(

Comment: Why do you want to kill the thread?  There is no guarantee that `Thread.Abort()` will do what you want, when you want it to.

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker (because it takes care of the details and makes life much easier in WebForms) and give it cancellation support? It is generally best if a thread "knows how to end itself" ..

Comment: @Bryan Crosby 
I have a chat program with a file transfer and I have a form with progressBar when close this form I want to cancel the thread

Comment: So you don't want to cancel from `Send_File`, you want to cancel from somewhere else?

Comment: @ Austin Salonen that  I use new form in Send_File in other word in another class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare your thread globally like any other variable (eg. int or string) you are using in different functions:

```
Thread My_Thread; //goes before your functions/main method
```

and then use it:

```
private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    My_Thread = new Thread(Send_File);
    My_Thread.IsBackground = true;
    My_Thread.Start();
}
```

and kill it:

```
private void Send_File()
{
    MyThread.Abort();
}
```

If you are talking about Send_File running in the thread, just exit it for example using `break`, stop all loops to complete it.

EDIT:
As Austin Salonen has stated in his comment this would overwrite the thread reference. My suggestion would be using a thread list.

```
public List<Thread> ThreadList=new List<Thread>(); //goes before your functions/main method (public for use in other classes)
```

and use it:

```
private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread My_Thread = new Thread(Send_File);
    My_Thread.IsBackground = true;
    My_Thread.Start();
    int ThreadIndex = ThreadList.Count; //remember index
    ThreadList.Add(My_Thread);
}
```

You just need to remember the index of the list to create a reference to the thread again.

To abort a thread just use its index:

```
ThreadList[ThreadIndex].Abort();
ThreadList[ThreadIndex] = null;
```

or just let the thread return.

Comment: What happens when but_Click is invoked multiple times?

Comment: Multiple threads will be started and they will be running until you either abort them using `MyThread.Abort()` or you return from them like in a console application. A console application is usually ended when there are no more methods/tasks to execute.

Comment: How can you abort the first thread when the second thread overwrote its reference?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I did not see that. My idea would be to use a thread list.

Answer (score 0):

Define the Thread at the class level:

```
public class Whatever
{
    Thread My_Thread;

    private void but_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        My_Thread = new Thread(() => Send_File());
        //...
    }

    private void Send_File()
    {
        My_Thread.Abort()  //though I can never ever ever encourage doing this
        //...
    }
}
```

Or just return. When a Thread's work method returns, it is killed.

Comment: What happens when but_Click is invoked multiple times?

Comment: I can't I have 2 reason the first if press but 2 time and the second reason I use new form in Send_File in other word My_Thread.Abort() in another class

Comment: @AustinSalonen good point. Hadn't thought of that when I wrote this up. Note that this isn't the way I'd do any of this, so maybe I'm not the best advice-giver on this.

Comment: @motaz99 then you need to just let the thread return. There is almost never a reason to explicitly abort a thread

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend you not use Thread directly if you need to abort what it's doing.  I'd recommend a Task and using `CancellationTokenSource` to communicate cancellation requests.  If you need to communicate with the UI, e.g. progress, I'd recommend a `BackgroundWorker`.  If you must use `Thread`, then you need to inform the user to abort.  You can do this by using a shared boolean value that the thread periodically checks to see if it should continue.  You should read/write the value in a thread-safe way.  Maybe `Interlocked.Exchange` would do that for you or `Thread.VolatileRead` and `Thread.VolatileWrite`...

When you use Thread.Abort it simply stops the thread unless the thread tries to catch the `ThreadAbortException`.  It's a bit iffy when you start using exceptions for normal logic flow; but, it's doable.  There is a potential for deadlock with `Thread.Abort` in the context of `try/catch/finally` blocks. (and any other constrained region)  But, `Thread.Abort` is not all that recommended: http://haacked.com/archive/2004/11/12/how-to-stop-a-thread.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Abort() is the one you're looking for.

References & useful pages:

- ["Thread.Abort Method"  [msdn.microsoft.com]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort(v=vs.71).aspx)